# Placing $n$ linear functions so that it is best fit to another function in integral norm sense?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, optimization, linear-approximation

Say we want to build a function which is piecewise linear $$f(x) = \sum_{\forall k} (H(x-x_k)-H(x-x_{k+1}))l_k(x)\\l_k(x) = c_{k1}x+c_{k2}$$

And also so that it fits best possibly some function $x\to g(x)$: $$l_k,x_k=\min_{l_k,x_k}\left\{\int_a^b |f(x)-g(x)|dx\right\}$$

Please note that the line end point coordinates $x_k$ we can decide for ourselves.

---

I've made some numerical approaches which seem promising on this, but how can one approach it algebraically/analytically?

Comment: If $H(x_k)$ represents the unit step function translated to $x_k$ the notation would be better  $f(x) = \sum_{\forall k}\left(H(x-x_{k})-H(x-x_{k+1})\right)l_k(x)$

Comment: Yes it is intended to be "active between $x_k$ and $x_{k+1}$". Feel free to edit if you want.

Comment: This kind of problem can be successfully handled with evolutionary programming -Evolution Strategies. See papers with those authors: Thomas Back, Gunter Rudolph, Hans-Paul Schwefel,

Comment: @Cesareo sounds interesting. Are they related to genetic algorithms?

Comment: Evolution Strategies have an Evolutionary paradigm but they use for each parameter real numbers instead a fractionary representation (chromosome). There are very efficient algorithms (CMA-ES) which converge in difficult non-convex situations.

Comment: Regularized convex or linear optimization seems much easier in my opinion, but that is probably because I have not done many of these evolution things. Feel free to make an answer if you want to show how it works.

Comment: Perhaps the method could be presented better applied to a case study. Do you have such an example to solve?

Comment: @Cesareo I showed my approach. Feel free to show yours.

Comment: I will prepare an example ASAP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a CMA-ES setup with ($\lambda = 20,\mu = 3$) over a test function

$$
f(x) = \text{If}\left[x<2.2 (x-2)^2+14,\text{If}\left[x<6.5 \sin \left(\frac{3}{2}  (x+4)\right)+2,-\frac{(x-6)^2}{0.3}-4\right]\right]
$$

with a chromosome composed of $2n+1$ parameters asigned as follows

$$
\phi_x = \{\Delta x_1,\cdots,\Delta x_n\}\\
\phi_y = \{y_1,\cdots,y_{n+1}\}
$$

Here $\Delta x_k = x_k-x_{x-1}$ for $k = 1,\cdots, n$ with $x_0$ as the lower number in the smoothing interval $[x_{min},x_{max}]$ so $x_0 = x_{min}$. Then $x_k = x_0+\sum_{j=1}^k\Delta x_j$ uses the pairs $\{x_k,y_k\}$ to construct a reference step-wise linear basis to proceed the integration process and the fitness is calculated as

$$
\sum_{k=1}^{n}\int_{x_k}^{x_{k+1}}|f(x)-g_k(\phi_x,\phi_y,x)|dx
$$

with

$$
g_k(\phi_x,\phi_y,x)=y_k + \frac{(y_{k+1}-y_k)}{(x_{k+1}-x_k)}(x-x_k)
$$

Follows a series of outcomes for established $n$ values

$(n = 4)$
[image]

$(n=5)$
[image]

$(n=6)$
[image]

$(n=7)$
[image]

$(n=8)$
[image]

$(n=9)$
[image]

$(n=10)$
[image]

Follows also a typical medium fitness progress curve

[image]

Comment: Ok thanks for contribution, maybe I will be able to check in weekend.

Answer (score 1):

One numerical approach we can take is to discretize the function into $N$ samples, construct a polynomial basis for each sample, and create a reweighted linear least squares problem:

$${\bf c_i} = \min_{\bf c} \left\{\|{\bf W_{1,i}}({\bf (\Phi\otimes 1_N) c}-{\bf f})\|_F^2 + \|{\bf W_{2,i}(D\otimes I_N)c}\|_F^2+\|{\bf (R\otimes I_N)c}\|_F^2\right\}$$

1. First term enforces model fit to function.
2. Second term enforces derivative ($\bf D$) of coefficients over time to be low. Remember we need an interval of points to have same coefficients within whole interval in order to be represented by model.

$${\bf W_{1,i}} = \max{[|({\bf \Phi \otimes 1_N)c_{i-1} - f}|^{k_1},1]}$$

$${\bf W_{2,i}} = \frac{1}{\max{[|({\bf D \otimes I_N)c_{i-1}}|^{k_2},1]}}$$

Lastly, we need $\bf R$ to punish any coefficients except for constant and linear terms.

Of course lots of details are left out, we need to normalize matrices and add parameters and tune a little bit of this and a little bit of that.

Example of a solution after 6 iterations:

[image]

The re-weighting in the iteration here is crucial to be able to achieve such flat lines as just one linear least squares punishes 2-norm and very rarely achieves sparse solutions. We can see how the interval of constant coefficients correspond to a unique line (red is the output of algorithm, trying to fit the blue function):

[image]